# How to get specific from attributes from a form variable object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please I have a little problem, i want to retrieve or set the form attribute found in a variable.
The variable contains a form object, for which i suppose I should be able to get for example an input field with the id="cusID".
 I have tried this but it doesnt seem to do what i want. Any idea what I am missing

```
var form = $('form[data-validate="true"][id="form"]');
```

So now if i want to access the elements on the selected form , i do this

```
var check = ( form +'[id=CusID], '+ form +'[id=email]');
```

But I get this [object Object][id=CusID], [object Object][id=email]"
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For the sake of the person coming after you change `$('form[data-validate="true"][id="form"]');` to `$('#form[data-validate="true"]');` and as written below. `$('[id=idname]')` is the same as `$('#idname')`

Comment: Given that id attributes should be unique to the page, you can simplify the selectors to just `$('#form')`, `$('#CusID')` and `$('#email')`

Comment: take what Rory McCrossan said and try to make simple as much as you can

Answer (score 2):

try `find`:-

```
var check = $(form).find('[id=CusID],[id=email]');
```

or:-

```
$('#CusID, #email');
```

As `id`'s must/should be unique.